# Convert a PEM-formatted String to a java.security.cert.X509Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

How does one create a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` instance from a PEM-formatted String?  The PEM-formatted String is a HTTP request "SSL_CLIENT_CERT" header value.

**ANSWER**:
*Based on mgaert's answer, here's what I wrote in Scala*:

```
val cert = factory.generateCertificate(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(
      Base64.decodeBase64(
        cert.stripPrefix("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----").stripSuffix("-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
      )
    ).asInstanceOf[X509Certificate]
```

Comment: There is no need to decode it. The PEM base64 encoded format is directly supported, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9739366/822870). Again:
CertificateFactory cFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cFactory.generateCertificate(getInputStream(of_the_original_unmodified_certificate_file));

Comment: it seems there is no need to strip the prefix/suffix as well

Comment: Doing Base64 decoding here can give you an Illegal Base64 character exception and so echoing the accepted answer and @DavidBalažic 's comment, there isn't a need to perform decoding here.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Decode the Base64 to binary, with some InputStream reading it, then try

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(is);
```

Comment: actually, there is no need to decode. @shuyu answer work like a charm

Comment: Oh, @ursa and @shuyu you are right - no decoding needed. My first thought was ... "and was that true in *March 2012* when I wrote that answer?" *Yes*! I dug up the JDK 7 source, and sure enough `generateCertificate` is *documented* to not only support binary, but Base64 as well. Plus, quote, "If the certificate is provided in Base64 encoding, it must be bounded at the beginning by -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----, and must be bounded at the end by -----END CERTIFICATE-----." Thanks for sending me on small time-travel trip here :-)

Answer (score 28):

I have a similar problem, I'm pasting also here the java code that worked for me in case anyone neaded it :

```
import java.util.Base64;

public static X509Certificate parseCertificate(String _headerName, HttpServletRequest _request) throws CertificateException {
    String certStr = _request.getHeader("x-clientcert");
    //before decoding we need to get rod off the prefix and suffix
    byte [] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certStr.replaceAll(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT, "").replaceAll(X509Factory.END_CERT, ""));

    return (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to strip the header and footer for PEM encoded X509 certs, see [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate(java.io.InputStream)).

Answer (score 15):

Tried to follow @Balaji Boggaram Ramanarayan code but IDE keep on throwing Exception. Instead i convert the string to bytes and it works perfectly.

```
private X509Certificate convertStringToX509Cert(String certificate) throws Exception{
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate.getBytes());
    return (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory
            .getInstance("X509")
            .generateCertificate(targetStream);
}
```

Not to mentions, this method doesn't need to remove .pem header and footer (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY-----)

Answer (score 11):

The steps in conversion of PEM formatted String is opposite of how (x509 -> String) took place.

Sample PEM Formatted String :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEczCCA1ugAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFAD..AkGA1UEBhMCR0Ix
EzARBgNVBAgTClNvbWUtU3RhdGUxFDASBgNVBAoTC0..0EgTHRkMTcwNQYD
VQQLEy5DbGFzcyAxIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcn..XRpb24gQXV0aG9y
aXR5MRQwEgYDVQQDEwtCZXN0IENBIEx0ZDAeFw0wMD..TUwMTZaFw0wMTAy
MDQxOTUwMTZaMIGHMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjETMBEGA1..29tZS1TdGF0ZTEU
MBIGA1UEChMLQmVzdCBDQSBMdGQxNzA1BgNVBAsTLk..DEgUHVibGljIFBy
aW1hcnkgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkxFD..AMTC0Jlc3QgQ0Eg
THRkMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCg..Tz2mr7SZiAMfQyu
vBjM9OiJjRazXBZ1BjP5CE/Wm/Rr500PRK+Lh9x5eJ../ANBE0sTK0ZsDGM
ak2m1g7oruI3dY3VHqIxFTz0Ta1d+NAjwnLe4nOb7/..k05ShhBrJGBKKxb
8n104o/5p8HAsZPdzbFMIyNjJzBM2o5y5A13wiLitE..fyYkQzaxCw0Awzl
kVHiIyCuaF4wj571pSzkv6sv+4IDMbT/XpCo8L6wTa..sh+etLD6FtTjYbb
rvZ8RQM1tlKdoMHg2qxraAV++HNBYmNWs0duEdjUbJ..XI9TtnS4o1Ckj7P
OfljiQIDAQABo4HnMIHkMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQ8urMCRL..5AkIp9NJHJw5TCB
tAYDVR0jBIGsMIGpgBQ8urMCRLYYMHUKU5AkIp9NJH..aSBijCBhzELMAkG
A1UEBhMCR0IxEzARBgNVBAgTClNvbWUtU3RhdGUxFD..AoTC0Jlc3QgQ0Eg
THRkMTcwNQYDVQQLEy5DbGFzcyAxIFB1YmxpYyBQcm..ENlcnRpZmljYXRp
b24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MRQwEgYDVQQDEwtCZXN0IENBIE..DAMBgNVHRMEBTAD
AQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQC1uYBcsSncwA..DCsQer772C2ucpX
xQUE/C0pWWm6gDkwd5D0DSMDJRqV/weoZ4wC6B73f5..bLhGYHaXJeSD6Kr
XcoOwLdSaGmJYslLKZB3ZIDEp0wYTGhgteb6JFiTtn..sf2xdrYfPCiIB7g
BMAV7Gzdc4VspS6ljrAhbiiawdBiQlQmsBeFz9JkF4..b3l8BoGN+qMa56Y
It8una2gY4l2O//on88r5IWJlm1L0oA8e4fR2yrBHX..adsGeFKkyNrwGi/
7vQMfXdGsRrXNGRGnX+vWDZ3/zWI0joDtCkNnqEpVn..HoX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here are the steps :

```
1. Remove headers from PEM formatted String
Headers are : ---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE ----- and ----- END CERTIFICATE ------
2. Decode the rest of the part using Base64 to byte array
3. Then you can use CertificateFactory to convert byte stream to x509Certificate object
```

Sample Code to do above (with PEM Writer):

```
  /**
     * Converts a PEM formatted String to a {@link X509Certificate} instance.
     *
     * @param pem PEM formatted String
     * @return a X509Certificate instance
     * @throws CertificateException 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public X509Certificate convertToX509Certificate(String pem) throws CertificateException, IOException {
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(pem);
        PEMReader pr = new PEMReader(reader);
        cert = (X509Certificate)pr.readObject();
        return cert;
    }
```

Comment: Note that PEMReader is part of Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs, see https://www.bouncycastle.org/. The code by @mgaert works without an external library.

Comment: `PEMReader` was in Bouncy 'core' (bcprov) only until 1.46 (2011-02) and then bcpkix until 1.49 (2013-05); after that it's replaced by `PEMParser` (with `PemReader` note lowercase as a separable factor).

Answer (score 7):

Another sample,

```
public static X509Certificate convertToX509Cert(String certificateString) throws CertificateException {
    X509Certificate certificate = null;
    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {
        if (certificateString != null && !certificateString.trim().isEmpty()) {
            certificateString = certificateString.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n", "")
                    .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", ""); // NEED FOR PEM FORMAT CERT STRING
            byte[] certificateData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificateString);
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
            certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateData));
        }
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        throw new CertificateException(e);
    }
    return certificate;
}
```

Comment: `Base64.getMimeDecoder()` can be a safer option, other wise you may see issues like `Illegal base64 character a` as discussed here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213780.

Comment: @34m0 that is exactly what happened to me. Thank you a lot for adding this comment!